# Use DTAP TFvars Modules in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

My goal is to implement Log Analytic Workspace within Terraform via Modules & TFvars to use this for other environments (DTAP). I am trying this for Test but I am getting an error:

## Folder Structure

**env-tfvars\mg-sandbox-d.tfvars**

```
tfvars_resource_group_name  = "rg-ter-mg-sandbox"
tfvars_storage_account_name = "censored"
tfvars_container_name       = "tfstate"
tfvars_key                  = "censored.terraform.tfstate"

location = "westeurope"

log-workspace-application-name = "test-law"
```

**modules\log-analytic-workspace\main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "log-workspace-application" {
  name                = var.log-workspace-application-name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.tfvars_resource_group_name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
}
```

**modules\log-analytic-workspace\variables.tf**

```
variable "log-workspace-application-name" {
  type = string
}

variable "location" {
  type = string
}

variable "tfvars_resource_group_name" {
  type = string
}
```

**$\main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg-test" {
  name     = var.tfvars_resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}

module "log-analytic-workspace" {
  source              = "./modules/log-analytic-workspace"
  name                = var.log-workspace-application-name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.tfvars_resource_group_name
  depends_on          = [azurerm_resource_group.rg-test]
}
```

**$\variables.tf**

```
variable "location" {
  type = string
}

variable "tfvars_resource_group_name" {
  type = string
}
variable "tfvars_storage_account_name" {
  type = string
}
variable "tfvars_container_name" {
  type = string
}
variable "tfvars_key" {
  type = string
}


variable "log-workspace-application-name" {
  type = string
}
```

## Error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to use DTAP TFvars Modules in Terraform to create log_analytics workspace I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The error message indicates that the `log-workspace-application` module is missing the required arguments `tfvars_resource_group_name` and `log-workspace-application-name`.

To fix this error, you need to pass these arguments to the module when you instantiate it in your `main.tf` file.

**Folder_Structure:**

```
.
├── env-tfvars
│   └── mg-sandbox-d.tfvars
├── modules
│   └── log-analytic-workspace
│       ├── main.tf
│       └── variables.tf
├── main.tf
└── variables.tf
```

**My terraform configuration:**

##### `env-tfvars/mg-sandbox-d.tfvars:`

```
tfvars_resource_group_name  = "demovksb"
location                    = "east us 2"
log_workspace_name          = "demovk"
```

##### `modules/log-analytic-workspace/main.tf:`

```
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "log_workspace" {
  name                = var.log_workspace_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.tfvars_resource_group_name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
}
```

##### `modules/log-analytic-workspace/variables.tf:`

```
variable "log_workspace_name" {
  type = string
}

variable "location" {
  type = string
}

variable "tfvars_resource_group_name" {
  type = string
}
```

##### main.tf:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg_test" {
  name     = var.tfvars_resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}

module "log-analytic-workspace" {
  source                    = "./modules/log-analytic-workspace"
  log_workspace_name        = var.log_workspace_name
  location                  = var.location
  tfvars_resource_group_name = var.tfvars_resource_group_name
  depends_on                = [azurerm_resource_group.rg_test]
}
```

##### variables.tf:

```
variable "location" {
  type = string
}

variable "tfvars_resource_group_name" {
  type = string
}

variable "log_workspace_name" {
  type = string
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see what you did and I understand it fully. Thank you very much for your detailed explanation.